# Why angularjs $apply is noop() on slickgrid's onColumnsReordered callback?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, slickgrid

I'm using SlickGrid v2.2 with angularjs.
after reordering columns on the grid further scope changes are being made, so I need to call scope.$apply as follows:

```
grid.onColumnsReordered.subscribe(function (e, args) {
    scope.$apply(function () {
        onColumnsReordered(grid.getColumns());
    });
});
```

upgrading angularjs to v1.2.16 resulted in getting scope.$apply to be noop(), as well as $digest, and the $parent and $root fields are null.
I've tried the latest v1.3 and it happens there as well.
on v1.2.15 and below and it does not happen.

Why scope.$apply is noop()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was a $destroy somewhere on the code, that is probably only relevant to an older version.
Removing these $destroy solved all the problems.